# how to disable tooltips ctrl:columnhtml

Tags: jsp, struts, common-controls

I have this simple code in a jsp with common-controls

```
<ctrl:list action="something.do" name="carList" title="label.t">

    <ctrl:columnhtml title ="label.commissionNumber" property="commissionNumber">

</ctrl:columnhtml>      


</ctrl:list>
```

When i move the mouse over the column's title, a tooltip is showed, and I couldn't remove it.
How can I disable this feature?

Comment: Remove `title` attribute.

Comment: Try adding tooltip="" to the column. Not submitting as an answer as I haven't tested it, its basically a guess from looking at the tag library.

Comment: I had already tried all the tricks that you suggested, without success. The title is mandatory, and the "tooltip" option seems to be ignored